# Remotely setting wallpaper on demand via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a function `Set-Wallpaper`:

```
Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
{
    Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
    rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}
```

and can run it locally to use a network path to the desired jpg

```
Set-Wallpaper -value "\\server\share\image.jpg"
```

and it works.

Now I want to run this function on a remote PC, I tried

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TARGETPC Set-Wallpaper -value "\\server\share\image.jpg"
```

but it errors out with
`Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'value'.`

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$session= new-pssession -Computername "yourClientname"
$reslt= Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {your code}
```

If u want to ahnd over an argument use it like this

```
$reslt= Invoke-Command -Session $session -argumentlist $argument  -ScriptBlock {param ($argument) your code with $argument[0]}
```